Issues with my PC turning off while in use
My computer started having this problem a few days ago where it shut off around 4-5 minutes of playing Minecraft. After turning off shaders, my power supply off eco mode, and giving the inside of my PC a dusting, it restarts after about an hour or two after I start playing. It's livable, but annoying.
Is there a solutions? Will I have to buy a new power supply?

Been a while since I worked on PC internals but is it having a lot of updates/restarting to install/make the updates?  Are your fans working properly/its not overheating?

all internal temps are normal, the fans are spinning properly. one was spinning a bit slow and is spinning as fast as it should after i dusted

Does this happen only when playing Minecraft? Because it doesn't sound like a pure gaming issue, but just a generic pc malfunction

@pinckerman thats a good question. it seems to only happen when playing minecraft. i would have to varify (i literally only play minecraft on that pc lol)

when you say "it shuts off", do you mean that it completely crashes, or does it display the windows "your PC is turning off" screen beforehand?

also please specify: is this a laptop or a tower, and what are the specs? When is the last time you changed the thermal paste (if you don't know what it is -> when did you buy it)?

@Themoonisacheese sure. It is a tower, i built it around 2020, don't know what the specs are though i can get them to you guys later today. have not changed the thermal paste since assembly which in hindsight is probably not the greatest.
it just shuts off with no "your PC is turning off" screen, and then turns back on

4-year oldd thermal paste isn't great but it's not the end of the world usually. when you dusted the PC, did you clean the radiators (ideally with canned air) or was it just the inside surfaces? my guess is that your power supply is full of dust, unless you made sure to clean it.

@Themoonisacheese I didn't have canned air so I'll be sure to purchase some. I dusted as thoroughly as i could with a microfiber cloth though i couldn't get to the more isolated places

then this is most likely your issue, as well as the hidden surfaces in the radiators. do try to clean them with canned air (or an air compressor) before going out all the way to buy a new PSU. make sure to do it outside, there's 4 years worth of dust in there!
